# Boost::test and mocking framework

Tags: c++, testing, boost, mocking

I am using boost::test and need to use a mocking framework with it.  Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently did a search for unit testing and mocking frameworks for my latest project and went with [Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/). It had the best documentation and seems fairly well featured (although I haven't created very complex mock objects yet). I initially was thinking of using `boost::test` but ended up using [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) instead (I think it's a prerequisite for Google Mock, even if you use another testing framework). It also has good documentation and has had most of the features I expected.

Answer (score 13):

[Fake-It](https://github.com/eranpeer/FakeIt) is a simple mocking framework for C++ uses the latest C++11 features to create an expressive (yet very simple) API.
With FakeIt there is no need for re-declaring methods nor creating a derived class for each mock and it has a built-in boost::test integration.
Here is how you Fake-It:

```
struct SomeInterface {
  virtual int foo(int) = 0;
};

// That's all you have to do to create a mock.
Mock<SomeInterface> mock; 

// Stub method mock.foo(any argument) to return 1.
When(Method(mock,foo)).Return(1);

// Fetch the SomeInterface instance from the mock.
SomeInterface &i = mock.get();

// Will print "1"
cout << i.foo(10);
```

There are many more features to explore. Go ahead and [give it a try](https://github.com/eranpeer/FakeIt).

Answer (score 6):

You can try [Turtle](http://turtle.sf.net) !

Comment: What are the advantages to Turtle?

Comment: Well, it's easily integrated with boost::test: you won't need all the workarounds that are required to make a boost::test project use gmock, for example (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890959/initgooglemock-causes-memory-leak-with-boosttest?noredirect=1#comment65142935_38890959).

Comment: Turtle's documentation is terse to  the point of being null. I don't think it is an advantage. Turtle is hard to use.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://alexott.net/en/cpp/CppTestingIntro.html#sec7) you've got an example of using Google Mock with Boost Test. I prefer Boost Test because I use other [Boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/) often.

Answer (score 2):

[GoogleMock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) has a section on using with [another framework](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies#Using_Google_Mock_with_Any_Testing_Framework).

Comment: Indeed, but it is still memory-leak-prone and requires workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890959/initgooglemock-causes-memory-leak-with-boosttest?noredirect=1#comment65142935_38890959

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

ELFSpy let's you replace (mock) functions, methods, virtual functions etc with alternate implementations at runtime.

https://github.com/mollismerx/elfspy/wiki